# Mozilla Closure Example

Tags: javascript, closures

[JS BIN Attempt](http://jsbin.com/ileva5/edit)

Attempting to follow along with the example, but it doesn't seem to work. A little confused, as it is Mozilla.

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Comment: [It does work](http://jsfiddle.net/6jjUG/1/)

Comment: @Raynos: it does, but you used jsfiddle, which has an option to execute JS code on page load, author of this question uses JS Bin, where I don't see similar option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't call `setupButtons` function on page load, only defined it. If you include jQuery, add:

```js
$(document).ready(setupButtons);
```

in you script tag and it'll work.

Comment: "If you include jQuery". Oh cmon `window.onload = setupButtons` or `setupButtons()` is easier. Stop using jQuery everywhere

Comment: Personally I don't use jQuery, at work I code in plain old JS, just assumed that author may use JQuery as it is most popular JS framework making JavaScript less ugly. And it forces using closures quite often, too.

Comment: Use JS and jQuery. I find both tools valuable. Also both answers valuable.

Answer (score 2):

As @Xaerxess mentions, you need to call the "setupButtons" function when the DOM is ready for manipulation; typically one does that by adding an event handler to the window "load" event, which happens when the page is entirely loaded (which is what the jQuery idiom `$(document).ready(function(){...});` does.

Try adding this snippet to the end of your existing `<script>` element to accomplish that goal using plain JavaScript, no jQuery needed:

```
window.onload = function() { setupButtons(); };
```

Another typical way of doing this is to use the [element.addEventListener function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener); the difference is that you can add multiple event callbacks this way and they won't overwrite each other:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  setupButtons();
}, false);
```